# Extending Typescript Type with custom method in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am building an angular 2 project  with the CLI.

I need to add a custom method to the String type like this.

```
interface String {
    foo(): number;
}

String.prototype.foo= function() {
    return 0;
}
```

Is that correct and where can I put this code in the project to make it works.The compiler still complains.
Can anyone help me to have the expected behaviour ?

Comment: You code is working my compiler does not complain

Comment: in which file  do you put the code for an angular project?

Comment: I just copy paste your code to one of my component to check it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell typescript about this, if you are working with angular cli you can put this in your **typings.d.ts** file:

```
  interface String {
    foo(): number;
  }
```

Comment: It get this mesage : cannot redeclared block-scoped variable String

Comment: Which ide you are using?

Comment: visual studio code. the error message is also written in the angular cli command line. which ide do you use?

Comment: I'm using webstorm